# find index of key in array of objects in javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

Suppose I have an array of objects:

```
var a = [
    {id: "1", "name": "ABC"}, 
    {id: "2", "name": "XYZ"},
    {id: "3", "name": "PQR"},
    {id: "4", "name": "JKL"}
];
```

I need to find the index of object which has the key "id: '3' " in it. Is there any way to find the index of the object using underscore library?
I have achieved this using for loop, but want to know an easier approach.

Comment: _.findIndex perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

In ECMAScript 6 you can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
[
    {id: "1", "name": "ABC"}, 
    {id: "2", "name": "XYZ"},
    {id: "3", "name": "PQR"},
    {id: "4", "name": "JKL"}
].findIndex(o => o.id === "3"); // 2
```

Similarly, underscore also has [`_.findIndex`](http://underscorejs.org/#findIndex):

```
_.findIndex([
    {id: "1", "name": "ABC"}, 
    {id: "2", "name": "XYZ"},
    {id: "3", "name": "PQR"},
    {id: "4", "name": "JKL"}
], function(o){ return o.id === "3"}); // 2
```